# Windows Embedded ignores ErrorMode setting

Tags: windows, embedded

I'm trying to get Windows Embedded Standard 7 SP1 from popping up a dialog box when an application crashes.  According to the documentation I've been able to find, setting the registry variable ErrorMode to 2 should do this.  And, in fact, on both Windows XP and Windows 7 Pro it worked as documented.

WES7 appears to be ignoring it completely.

I've tried setting the ErrorMode DWORD to 2 in all of these places:

- HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows
- HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows
- HKCU\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows

I've also added a HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PCHealth key and set all of the appropriate values in there to ZERO to ensure that nothing can pop up.

But alas, when I [intentionally] write to a NULL pointer, instead of my program just being terminated immediately (as happened in XP and 7 Pro) I am rewarded with a dialog telling my that my program has stopped working and offering a single button to terminate it.

WES7 has a "Message Box Interceptor" that will automatically give the default response to any MessageBox that appears, but (a) I don't believe this is actually a MessageBox and (b) I cannot have my APPLICATION's message boxes treated that way.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: THANKS!  Strangely, DISABLED was already set to 1, but adding DONTSHOWUI and setting *it* to 1 did the trick.  Plus, we still get the crash recorded in the event log, which helps, too.  If you want to repost an answer, I'll mark it as such.